# Apply a CSS or SASS rule to an element only if it has a specific child element

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I have a some HTML like so

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1"></div>
   <div class="child2"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1"></div>
</div>
```

i want the `.parent` to have a `width` of `300px` only if it has a `.child2` element.

Therefore the second `.parent` above would not have a `width` of `300px` because it doesn't have a child with a `.child2` class.

In CSS or SASS. i have no idea on how to approach this. And in my particular case, javascript is not an option

Comment: @paulie_D how about SASS?

Comment: SASS still outputs CSS. If it can't be done in CSS then SASS/LESS won't help.

Comment: It is absolutely not a duplicate and is possible in CSS and SASS. Please reopen the case @paulie_D so I can answer properly.

Comment: @paulie_D please open the question if  has an answer